# How do I start writing?

Tags: short-story, getting-started

I have so many great ideas! I've completed several stories in my head but i've never put any to paper. How do I start? How do you start?

Comment: If you've finished the stories in your head already, what's to stop you from writing them down?  I'm not sure what your difficulty is.  Writing is a long series of trial and error to get something right.  Not writing at all is the best way to not make progress.

Comment: Green, that's what I ask myself. I don't really know why I haven't started yet. It might be fear. It might be laziness. I'm just not sure.

Comment: How do you start? You put your fingers on the keyboard, set focus to Word or similar, and start typing. I'm not being trite here; the hardest part of writing IMHO is making that start. Write a sentence, then write another one. Keep going. Either the story will start to flow, or it won't. If it doesn't, skip down a bit and try starting again. Keep the bits you want to discard as they can be useful later on, or reflect an opportunity to restart an idea (come back to it). Once you get on a roll, writing isn't hard but you have to get the momentum going in the first place.

Comment: @Andrew I've added an answer on the duplicate for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tough question to answer, because everyone has different methods that work for them. What I would suggest is to literally just *start* writing about anything you want to write about. Put down words, even if they don't make grammatical or syntactical sense, because you can fix all that later. Just try and keep the thoughts flowing from your mind to the page. Also try completing some writing prompts and exercises if you're not sure where to go or how to start. This site writingexercises.co.uk has cured my writer's block so many times.